# Decrement update query

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am currently working on a website developed in ASP.NET. I'm using SignalR to post real time changes from the database. For example I have a Table which has messages and a `NewMessageCount`. Each time the `NewMessageCount` goes up the user gets notified. However my problem is when the user clicks on the Notification it doesn't decrement. E.g if the user has two notification and clicks on the `Message` tab it goes down to 0 rather than 1 and then 0.

Here is the code in the `Hub`

```
     [HubMethodName("removeNotifications")]
    public string RemoveNotifications()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Messages SET NewMessageCount=@NewMessageCount", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewMessageCount", totalNewMessages);
                    command.Notification = null;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    connection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
                IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
                return context.Clients.All.RemoveNotification(totalNewMessages);
    }
```

And to the `script` used on the client side is the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;

        notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (totalNewMessages) {   
            $('#spanNewMessages').text(totalNewMessages);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            notifications.server.sendNotifications();
            $('.Message').click(function () {
                notifications.server.removeNotifications();
        })
        });
});         
</script>
```

I might be making an obvious mistake but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance for all your help and support.

Comment: Where totalNewMessages gets updated on a server side?

Comment: @AlexArt. They get update in the `NewMessagecount` column

Comment: Maybe you should return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification (totalNewMessages);

Comment: @AlexArt. That gives me the exact same problem

Comment: put debugger; inside function (totalNewMessages) {   
            $('#spanNewMessages').text(totalNewMessages);
        }; and check what is the value of totalNewMessages

Comment: @AlexArt. The value is 2 in this case which is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by simply implementing the query to the following

```
string query = "UPDATE Messages SET NewMessageCount=NewMessageCount-1 WHERE UserName=@UserName AND NewMessageCount > 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    $(function () {
        var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;
        var newMessages;
        notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (totalNewMessages) { 
            newMessages = parseInt(totalNewMessages);
            $('#spanNewMessages').text(totalNewMessages);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            notifications.server.sendNotifications();
            $('.Message').click(function () {
                newMessages--;
                notifications.server.removeNotifications(newMessages);
        })
        });
});
```

Server:

```
 [HubMethodName("removeNotifications")]
    public string RemoveNotifications(int newMessages)
    {
        if(newMessages < 0)
        {
            return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(0);
        }
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Messages SET NewMessageCount=@NewMessageCount", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewMessageCount", newMessages);
                    command.Notification = null;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    connection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
                IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
                return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(newMessages);
    }
```